# How to remove error while is loading in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build a Shiny App, everything works ok, but my issue is at the beginning, the first time that my app is launched i get an error in my highcharts due the size of the data (more than 3M of rows),
After 10 seconds the error disapear and everithing looks ok, but i want to remove the error, now i'm using waiter package, loading screeen is displayed 1.5 seconds, then the error appear and later the graph is showed .
I want to use Waiter package to hide this error until every calculation is finished. This is the Error
[image: This is the error]

Below here my code for the graph

```
# Graph for shortInterest tab By CvsI (bars) --Dynamic
  output$graph_bars_shortInterest_hc <- renderHighchart({
    
    waiter_show(
      id = "graph_bars_shortInterest_hc",
      html = tagList(spin_fading_circles(), 
                     "Loading Model ..."),
      color = "#63666a",
      logo = "",
      hide_on_render = !is.null(id)
    )
    
    
    Client <- subset(Data_russel, Metrics == "marketCap") %>%
      filter(Value >= input$MC_bars_[1])%>%
      filter(Value <= input$MC_bars_[2])%>%
      select(Client_Name) %>% unique()
    
    Client_2 <- subset(Data_russel, Metrics == "Annual_Limit_Adequacy") %>%
      filter(Value >= input$AL_filter_[1])%>%
      filter(Value <= input$AL_filter_[2])%>%
      select(Client_Name) %>% unique()
    
    Data_Metric <- subset(Data_russel, Metrics == "shortInterest" & Industry %in% input$industry_CvsI_bars) 
    Client_filtered <- inner_join(Client, Client_2, by = "Client_Name")
    Data_ <- inner_join(Client_filtered, Data_Metric, by = "Client_Name") # Clients in the range of Selected Market cap
    
    Data_c <- subset(Data_russel, Metrics == "shortInterest" & Industry %in% input$industry_CvsI_bars & Client_Name == input$clientname_CvsI_bars) 
    
    
    Table_ <- seq(input$perc_range_[1], input$perc_range_[2], 1) %>% as.data.frame()
    names(Table_) <- "Percentile"
    Table_$Value <- round( quantile(Data_c$Value, Table_$Percentile/100), digits = 2)
    Table_$Industry <- round( quantile(Data_$Value, Table_$Percentile/100), digits = 2) 
    
    hc_1 <- Table_ %>% 
      hchart(. , type = "line", hcaes(x = Percentile, y = Value), name = "Client", color = "#FFB81C") %>% 
      hc_add_series(data = Table_ ,type = 'line' , color = "#00a0d2", name = "Industry", hcaes(x = Percentile, y = Industry))%>%
      hc_yAxis(opposite = TRUE) %>%
      hc_title(text = "shortInterest Benchmark", margin = 30,
               align = "center",
               style = list(color = "#702080", useHTML = TRUE)) %>%
      hc_yAxis(max = max(Table_$Industry)+(sd(Table_$Industry)/5))%>%
      hc_yAxis(min = min(Table_$Industry)-(sd(Table_$Industry)/5))%>%
      hc_add_theme(hc_theme_google())
    
    hc_1
    
    
  })
```

Thanks !!

Comment: Can you provide a MWE?

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, what is MWE?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed using next function, and using each output in the UI into this function

````
  output %>% withSpinner(
    type = getOption("spinner.type", default = 3), 
    color.background = getOption("spinner.color.background", default = "#C8D7DF" ),
    color="#00A0D2")
  }```
````